# How to redirect a single web page from one domain to another using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I get the following redirect to work?

```
olddomain.com/employee-scheduling-software.html
```

To redirect to

```
newdomain.us/employee-scheduling-software.html
```

I do have mod_rewrite on, but I'm basically a complete novice in this area

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^employee-scheduling-software.html$ http://newdomain.example.org/employee-scheduling-software.html
</IfModule>
```

You can change the rule into:

```
RewriteRule ^employee-scheduling-software.html$ http://newdomain.example.org/employee-scheduling-software.html [R=301]
```

which will send a `301 Moved Permanently` header to the browser, so it updates its bookmarks and stuff.

Comment: It turns out this got the job done, thanks for your help.

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^olddomain\.com$

RewriteRule ^employee-scheduling-software\.html$ http://newdomain.us/employee-scheduling-software.html [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code in .htaccess on olddomain.com:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^employee-scheduling-software\.html$ http://newdomain.us/employee-scheduling-software.html [R,QSA]
```

*Since the `^employee-scheduling-software\.html$` is a PERL regex, you need to escape the dot in ".html" with a backslash (`\.`).*

This will just redirect `employee-scheduling-software.html` to the new domain. If you want to redirect all files to the new domain, use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.us/$1 [R,QSA]
```