# redirect a webpage to wordpress url in apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a webpage, say, www.xyz.com/contests.html.

I wish to redirect it to http://example.com/contests/ at server level [using apache .htaccess]. This new url is a wordpress link.

How do I do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: There are literally hundreds of questions on Stack Overflow alone, and literally thousands of pages on the Internet explaining how .htaccess redirection works. When you tried to do it yourself, what was the problem that you encountered?

Comment: I tried a lot.. could not find exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect a single web page from one domain to another using .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692733/how-to-redirect-a-single-web-page-from-one-domain-to-another-using-htaccess)

Comment: aha.. I made a mistake in asking question.. redirect is to a wordpress url

Comment: Why would that make any difference?

Comment: you are right.. it would not make a difference. I tried the solutions given in the link that you sent.. no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is taken directly from my website.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^contests\.html$ http://example.com/contests.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Assuming you do have `mod_rewrite` (check!), the only reason I can think of for it not working is that you didn't describe your situation correctly and e.g. the redirection starts somewhere else than in the root directory. You may want to experiment with removing the anchors `(^, $)` and if you find it works, updating the regexp or RewriteBase to match your exact situation.

Comment: This code is taken directly from my website. Assuming you do have mod_rewrite (check!), the only reason I can think of for it not working is that you didn't describe your situation correctly and e.g. the redirection starts somewhere else than in the root directory. You may want to experiment with removing the anchors (`^`, `$`) and if you find it works, updating the regexp or `RewriteBase` to match your exact situation.

Comment: I am running many domains on my server. I have set up virtual host for different domains.

Comment: there is a .htaccess in the root folder of the domain concerned. I just added 3 and 4th line of your code to it

Comment: i think it is a problem of regex. the two redirect statements that work well in that file are RewriteRule    ^trend/([0-9]+)/?$    share.php?id=$1    [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^trend/?$    share.php   [NC,L]

Comment: Then try: `RewriteRule ^trend/contests\.html$ http://example.com/contests.html [R=301,L]`. That should definitely work if your examples work.

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess (of xyz.com) write the following:

## This allows you to redirect contests.html to a specific location

Redirect /contests.html http://example.com/contests.html