# Issue Regarding .htaccess Redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have some issue regarding .htaccess redirection. I have checked a post regarding .htaccess redirection of one page to another domain page.

[How to redirect a single web page from one domain to another using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692733/how-to-redirect-a-single-web-page-from-one-domain-to-another-using-htaccess)

I have tried these code but when i use this code it is getting redirected but all the other pages on the old domain website are showing 404. Please help me.

Please note: I am not a developer and don't have any knowledge about the codes so please provide a simple solution so that i can directly implement on the website. I will be very greatful to you.....:)

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: Show us your `.htaccess` file content, and show us an example. What is the original url, and what is the new url?

Comment: I have solved that issue. But i am getting a new issue. The issue is that i have been trying to redirect multiple url but only my first url is getting redirected. Other urls are not redirecting. Please check the codes in the image for the codes:- http://imgur.com/a/N2Pj9 Only first url is redirecting not the 2nd one.