# Redirect a page from one domain to another domain (both domains belong to one website)

Tags: php, .htaccess

At first glanse question is pretty common, however other answers I have seen do not work in my case.
I need to redirect a page from one domain to another domain. Both domains have one web-site under them and one common .htaccess file.

> www.olddomain.com/guides -> www.newdomain.com

I use **.htaccess** file. If someone knows answer for other way - you are welcome also.

My current file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([a-z_\d]+)$ controller.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

I have tried this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 http://www.olddomain.com/guides https://www.newdomain.com

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([a-z_\d]+)$ controller.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Also I tried this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^http://www.olddomain.com/guides$ https://www.newdomain.com [R=301]

RewriteRule ([a-z_\d]+)$ controller.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Does not work. How it can be done properly?

Comment: I presume this .htaccess file is at the docroot of *olddomain.com*?

Comment: from here https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file, insert in old domain .htaccess  file the following line: Redirect 301 guides/ https://www.newdomain.com

Comment: @CD001 Both domains point to one web-site and have one common .htaccess

Comment: Your answer is probably here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3692748/2849202

Comment: @Roadowl Tried (see question updates) - not working.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your Redirect 301 line is the way to go, but should read something like this:

```
Redirect 301 /guides https://www.newdomain.com
```

See [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/) for more information.

Edit to add:
The above will redirect to `https://www.newdomain.com/`

If you want a certain path, then just put

```
Redirect 301 /guides https://www.newdomain.com/foo
```

where foo is the path on the server you want to end up at.

Comment: This "newdomain" also has /guides. So following this when I go to that link at newdomain it will redirect me to a home

Comment: @KirillCh
See my edit. You should be able to specify anywhere on `newdomain.com` to end up at by putting a full path.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This answer is not solving my question, however it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I end up with the following.

- Unlinked "olddomain" name from the origin site.
- Created new website folder at my hosting with only one file **.htaccess** in a root that contains only one line as @CBaish suggested:

> Redirect 301 /guides https://www.newdomain.com

- Linked "olddomain" to this folder

Now all traffic from the page "/guides" of olddomain will go to my newdomain.